# Can Raspberry Pi 3 connect to multiple bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth, connection, retropie

I plan to make a RetroPie gaming station using 8BitDo bluetooth controllers, and I need to know if i need to spend extra money on bluetooth adapters to support multiple connections for multiple controllers.

Some devices cannot support it and some others can, and so for the sake of my small budget, i would like to know if i would need to buy more adapters, or just have the controllers and the pi.

(If this is not clear: I need to know how many devices/controllers can connect to the Raspberry Pi 3's on board bluetooth).

Comment: What type of adapter is it?

Comment: Most BT adapters should support numerous connections, on average about 8 connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already have my pi3 running with Retropie and two ps3 gamepads connected by bluetooth and it works flawlessly, so it works without any problem.

Comment: Just to add more info on your answer. I'm connecting 2 PS3 gamepads(one clone - Shanwan, other Sony official), and they work good together with the same bluetooth.
However, you need to select the "Shanwan" driver to make both work, and the Sony controller will not show correctly the player led indicator(all 4 of them blinking). If you use the Sony driver, it will show correctly the player number, but the clone controller will not pair anymore.